Angular with no intellisense when inline stating a object as component property
Here is my component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inherited-style',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `<div [ngStyle]="styleTyped">inherited-style works!</div>`,
  styleUrl: './inherited-style.component.css'
})
export class InheritedStyleComponent {
   @Input() styleTyped!:Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>;
}


So on other component I would use:
    <app-inherited-style [styleTyped]="{}">

in order to have intellisense on styles like react does but I get:

Is it some miss config or angular can't intellisense a object on inline property bind statements ?

Can I ask why would you create such a component in the first place ?

I would like to style inline with intellisense like react does but [style] in angular is a generic object (so no intellisense) then I made an auxiliar component which has an object signed as Partial as its property, CSSStyleDeclaration is the type of some object like {backgroundColor:"red",padding:.....}

then I thought I'd get the intellisense for CSSStyleDeclaration properties

This does actually give suggestions in Webstorm for me. Note though that using CSSStyleDeclaration will means valid keys like 'fontStyle.rem' will be marked as wrong.

@Carcigenicate it's what I'd like , to fake style={{}} in react to angular, should I change my IDE?

@Carcigenicate can you check for me if Webstorm intellisense for [style] binding? ex: [style]="{'display':'block','color':true?'green':'red'}"

@DaviAmerico It does completion on the keys, but doesn't actually suggest values unfortunately.

Oh, CSSStyleDeclaration doesn't actually define values besides string, so that seems like it's the proper behavior.

Following my comment and your answer, you can do way simpler, without a component : just type your variable accordingly, and provide it directly to what you're trying to style :
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div [ngStyle]="styles">
      Your component content, styled
    </div>
  `,
  styles: `
    :host { display: contents; }
  `
})
export class InheritedStyleComponent {
   styles: CSSStyleDeclaration = { /* your intellisensed styles here */ };
}

EDIT NOTE : you should refrain from styling your application like this for design reasons : style takes precedence over any CSS you apply on the element, and since it's Javascript, you will just add more logic that might not be needed, resulting in a slower application eventually.

it's not an option because I always state inline, the problem is the intellisense inline not working, the use case of this problem is prime ng which has its default styles easily changed by using styles inline, I can do what you stated but I'd end up creating a component to any minimal UI using prime ng, I wouldn't like this

PrimeNG can also be configured with css only, you don't need ngStyle ... Not really a convincing argument !

by using inline styles I barely need to know what version of prime ng I'm using since it not depends from class names.

It seems that you're stubborn so I'll just leave it there then. After all, not my project, not my problem !

the one just can ignore the inline styles in order to read html template, it's extremly easy but it seems like people gets obsessed seeing it, you don't need to have any criativity to create class names, and worry about a "lost" .css in somewhere  bugging layout (for non angular projects) and as I stated they have maximum specifity, you can ensure the style will be as you stated without looking through  abstract details lost in your theme/ui lib etc in order to debug something
